# how to disable / prevent tidesdk appcelerator app-track

Tags: appcelerator, tidesdk

when I launch my application from TideSDK Developer, I can see that the app connects to the appcelerator server (https://api.appcelerator.net/p/v1/app-track) and tracks the usage of the app.

How can I disable this tracking? I tried to set a new entry in the tiapp.xml without any effect:

```
<analytics>false</analytics>
```

System:

- Mac OS
- TideSDK 1.3.1 (beta)
- TideSDK Developer 1.4.2

Thanks for any idea.

Greetings

--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer:

```
<analytics>false</analytics>
```

was in the window-block by mistake. It runs corectly when it's in the ti:app-block outside the window-block

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti='http://ti.appcelerator.org'>
<!-- These values are edited/maintained by TideSDK Developer -->
<id>myID</id>
<name>myAppName</name>
<version>1.0</version>
<publisher>me</publisher>
<url>no-site</url>
<icon>default_app_logo.png</icon>
<copyright>2015...</copyright>
<analytics>false</analytics>
<!-- Window Definition - these values can be edited -->
  <window>
    <id>initial</id>
    <title>myTitle</title>
    <url>app://index.html</url>
    <width>800</width>
    <max-width>3000</max-width>
    <min-width>0</min-width>
    <height>600</height>
    <max-height>3000</max-height>
    <min-height>0</min-height>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <resizable>true</resizable>
    <chrome scrollbars="true">true</chrome>
    <maximizable>true</maximizable>
    <minimizable>true</minimizable>
    <closeable>true</closeable>
  </window>
</ti:app>
```